# Test Unity method that uses local private SerializedField

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to check the content of clockText.text after a couple of seconds.

```cs
public class Clock : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    TextMeshProUGUI clockText;

    TextMeshProUGUI ClockText { get { return clockText; } }

    float remainingSeconds = 0f;

    public void StartCountDown(int seconds)
    {
        remainingSeconds = seconds;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        remainingSeconds -= Time.deltaTime;
        ClockText.text = Math.Ceiling(remainingSeconds).ToString();            
    }
}
```

With this test:

```cs
public class TestClock
{
    [UnityTest]
    public IEnumerator ClockShowCorrectTime()
    {
        var clock = new GameObject().AddComponent<Components.Shot.Clock>();
        clock.StartCountDown(2);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        Assert.AreEqual("00:01", clock.ClockText.text);
    }
}
```

but of course `clock.ClockText` is null. And I would like to keep clockText as private, so I can't set clockText from the Test.

Should it be public because we can change it on Editor?

Comment: If you have to set it from another class then yes somehow it has to be `public` .. eihter use the `ClockText` property and add a `set` or use a method. If possible you could also use `GetComponent` or one of its versions to get the reference on runtime

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new instance of `Clock` will not have its `clockText` member variable set because it's only settable in an inspector window, or when deserializing.

So your test will only work if you make `clockText` a public variable and set it yourself.

Another workaround is removing your dependency on a text field altogether and make the time value just a private string variable (with a public getter) so your clock can also run without a display field.

Comment: That last sentense is actually the best part of this answer! It is always better to have the actual value stored somewhere in the class itself for testing it instead of relying on some external representation of the same data

Comment: Doesn't have sense to me to have a component that doesn't display anything.

Comment: @TlmaK0 for the UnityTest it would like frankhermes said be far enough to make the Assert on a simple `string` field instead of a `Text` component ....